# How to look up a constant value from another table in a view efficiently (just once)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a view that needs to look up a configuration value and return it as one of the columns in every row of the view results.  This value is essentially a constant for the duration of the SELECT (and in fact, is generally constant for months on end, and is definitely different for every customer).  Here's a contrived example:

```
CREATE VIEW Baz
AS
   SELECT foo,
          (SELECT [Value] FROM [Config] WHERE [Key] = N'MyKey') AS ConstantValue,
          bar
     FROM myTable
```

The problem with this, is that the SQL plan shows that the value is being looked up for each and every row in the table.  This is a waste, and is definitely the "hot-spot" in the plan.  I'd like it to look up the value just ONCE, and then use it in every row.

Now, in this contrived example, the plan doesn't show it, but in every plan I make, no matter how I try to get that constant value (using a WITH CTE, CROSS APPLY the value into the results of the SELECT, etc.) the plan always shows that the Index Seek for the value happens once per row, not once TOTAL.

I can't hard code the value, because it's a configuration value that can and does change over time, and is definitely uniquely different for every customer database.

I'm showing as much as 40% of the query time (in both estimated and actual plans) being spent in just this one lookup.  Doing it ONCE would be a significant optimization.  Any ideas?

See the part of the plan below:

[image: Note the index Seek on SystemConfig]

Comment: Try to add the subquery as a table instead of a column and see the execution plan like `select  columns, tableconfig.column from table t, (subquery here) tableconfig`

Comment: Alas, that doesn't work (actually seems to slow things down just a fraction, according to the total subtree cost in the plan).  If this weren't a view, I'd just look it up, assign it to a variable, and just use the variable in the SELECT statement. Because it's a VIEW definition, I can't do something that simple or obvious, which is just frustrating.

Comment: How long does the query take to run?

Comment: What version of SQL are you running?  I have done similar things in SQL 2012 and it didn't display this behavior

Comment: All this is being done on 2008R2.  And I don't see the behavior in stand alone.  I only see it when the statement is unioned with another statement that doesn't use the same sub-select (which I found out after much trial and error).

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Move the expression to the `from` clause.  It will only be evaluated once:

```
CREATE VIEW Baz AS
   SELECT t.foo, k.ConstantValue, t.bar
   FROM myTable t CROSS JOIN
        (SELECT [Value] as ConstantValue FROM [Config] WHERE [Key] = N'MyKey') k;
```

Comment: Alas, I did try that (as stated in the question), both using a CTE, and in just the FROM, both using CROSS APPLY, and while the simple example works, the actual plan for the full VIEW (which is a union of several of these SELECTS, and the SELECTs themselves have additional JOINS), the plan still shows the value being read for each and every row.  It's really frustrating... in fact, doing this made it run even more slowly.

Comment: Try using CROSS JOIN as Gordon has it and not CROSS APPLY. They are two very different things.

Comment: Made that change, and it had zero effect.  It's still executing it once per row... the plan shows 5000+ rows coming out of that one index seek for the value, which is then joined with the table.  And it's still the most expensive part of the plan.

Comment: I've added an image of the plan with the CROSS JOIN version, so you can see what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW Baz
AS
   SELECT t.foo,
          c.Value AS ConstantValue,
          t.bar
      FROM myTable t
      join (SELECT [Value] FROM [Config] WHERE [Key] = N'MyKey') c on
         1 = 1
```

This executes the subquery just once, and joins the result to each row of MyTable.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't change the plan either.  Looks like there's no way to do this optimization in a VIEW (super easy in any other situation though... just look it up once, put it in a variable, and use that variable in the select statement).  Thanks for the idea though...